# Apps Script - OAuth consent screen and GWM Store Listing. Which is published first?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I have an Apps Script project for a Google Sheets Editor Add-on. It is linked to a GCP project.

In the GCP project, I completed the "OAuth consent screen". I also completed the "App Configuration" and "Store Listing" screens for the "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK".

The "OAuth consent screen" has a "Publish App" button. The "Store Listing" screen has a "Publish" button.

Which of these should be activated first? Is there a separate verification process for OAuth and the Marketplace listing or is there only one?.

[ Also: When I press Publish on the OAuth screen, it tells me I need to include a URL to a youtube video and a written explanation of why the apps require sensitive access. But I don't see any place to include this info on the form. How do I do this? ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You must finish the OAuth consent screen verification first, then complete the GWM store listing.

#### Explanation:

Both processes are completely different. The marketplace listing is just for your app to appear in the list of apps in the Google Workspace Marketplace, and the OAuth verification process is the security check that you have to pass in order for your app to be available for more than 100 users in case you use sensitive/restricted scopes that manage Google accounts' sensitive info, that is why this process requires a specific video showing how you are going to be using the users' data in your app with the selected scopes.

However, based in [Google's official documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/about-app-review#:%7E:text=The%20app%20has%20passed%20OAuth%20verification%2C%20uses%20the%20narrowest%20OAuth%20scopes%20possible%2C%20and%20all%20scopes%20integrate%20correctly%20with%20Google%20Services%20APIs.), you can't publish your app until you have passed the OAuth verification process because that is included in the review that Google does for the GWM store listing.

### References:

- [How OAuth verification differs from app review](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/configure-oauth-consent-screen#differs)
- [About app review](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/about-app-review)

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to also know how to send Google the video url and written explanation? Maybe I need to create another question for that.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz You should get an email from Google's Trust and Safety team who is the one in charge of doing the verifications. You can check that in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/create-listing#:~:text=For%20public%20app%20listings%2C%20you%20receive%20emails%20about%20its%20publication%20status%20during%20the%20review%20process) as well, so all the communication would be via email.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, from sample emails that others had received. But thanks for verifying it.

Comment: I clicked Publish on the OAuth consent screen and proceeded with the steps. Eventually I got to a screen where I could enter a written explanation and also add the Youtube URL. That's good that I don't need to wait for an email to respond to.